# parent child table sql issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, parent-child

i have 3 tables below which have many to many relation...In student table i have multiple foreign keys `sec_id,ad_id` but i dont know how to add foreign key as parent-child relation please help me out..

```
CREATE TABLE student(
s_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(s_id)
)

CREATE TABLE section(
sec_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(sec_id)
)


CREATE TABLE advisor(
ad_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ad_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a <kbd>student</kbd> can have at most *one* <kbd>advisor</kbd>, then it's a one-to-many relationship.

The normal pattern for implementing that relationship is to define a foreign key column in the child table, the table on the "many" side of the relationship. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD ad_id INT COMMENT 'fk ref advisor';
```

Further, some storage engines, like InnoDB, support and enforce foreign keys. That is, we can have the database enforce restrictions (constraints) on values that can be stored in columns defined as foreign keys.

For example, we can establish a rule that says that a value stored in the `ad_id` column in the `student` table... *must* be found in a row in the `advisor` table, in the `ad_id` column.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_advisor 
  FOREIGN KEY (ad_id) REFERENCES advisor(ad_id) 
  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This also enforces a rule that a row from `advisor` table cannot be deleted if there are rows in `student` table that reference it.

That same pattern can be repeated for any one to-to-many relationship. For example, if a <kbd>student</kbd> can be related to *at most* one <kbd>section</kbd> we can add a foreign key in the same way.

If there's a many-to-many relationship, then we introduce a *relationship* table that has foreign keys referencing the two related *entity* tables.

If a <kbd>student</kbd> can be related to zero, one or more <kbd>section</kbd>, and a <kbd>section</kbd> can be related to zero, one or more <kbd>student</kbd>, that's an example of a many-to-many relationship.

We can introduce a new table like this (as an example):

```
CREATE TABLE student_section 
( student_id  INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk, fk ref student'
, section_id  INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk, fk ref section'
, PRIMARY KEY (student_id, section_id)
, CONSTRAINT fk_student_section_student
    FOREIGN KEY student_id REFERENCES student(s_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT fk_student_section_section
    FOREIGN KEY section_id REFERENCES section(sec_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

With that in place, to establish a relationship between a <kbd>student</kbd> and a <kbd>section</kbd>, we insert a row to the new `student_section` table. If the <kbd>student</kbd> is related to another <kbd>section</kbd>, we add another row to the table, referencing the same student, but a different section.

The value stored in the `student_id` column refers to a row in the `student` table; and a value stored in the `section_id` column refers to a row in the `section` table.

(The many-to-many relationship is really composed of rows in a new table that has a one-to-many relationship to two other tables.)